# $\text{PGL}_n(K)$ is algebraic group, proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I was wondering if someone could help me with this proof. I want to show that $\text{PGL}_n(K)$ is an algebraic group, where $K$ is an algebraically closed field, so especially that it is an variety. For that, one could consider the map $\text{PGL}_n(K) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^{n^2-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{N}, [P] = [p_1, ..., p_{n^2}] \mapsto (... \frac{p^n}{\det(P)}...)$. With $p^n$ I mean all the monomials in the variables $p_1, ... ,p_{n^2}$ of degree $n$, this same notation is used for the Veronese map. This map should be well-defined, since $[\lambda P] = [\lambda p_1, ..., \lambda p_{n^2}] \mapsto (... \frac{\lambda^n p^n}{\lambda^n \det(P)}...) = (... \frac{p^n}{\det(P)}...)$. I know that if $X$ is a projective variety, then $X$ is isomorphic to the image of the $X$ under the Veronese map. Is that also true for affine varieties? If yes, then $(... \frac{p^n}{\det(P)}...)$ could be uniquely identified with some matrix $Q$ with determinant $1$, so this would imply $\text{PGL}_n(K) \cong \text{SL}_n(K)$. Is my argumentation correct?

Comment: What is $K$? I ask for many reasons, but one reason that is pertinent to your post is that the statement $PGL_n(K) \approx SL_n(K)$ is false in general.

Comment: Sorry, $K$ is an algebraically closed field

Comment: (for $K$ algebraically closed) $PGL_n(K) \cong SL_n(K) / \mu_n$ where $\mu_n$ is the set of scalar matrices with determinant 1, the kernel of $SL_n(K)\to PGL_n(K)$, that are all sent to the same through your Venonese map. Also it is unclear what you intend to do with the image of the Veronese map on $PGL_n(K)$, as it is immediate that $PGL_n(K)$ is a projective variety.

Comment: @reuns $\mathrm{PGL}_n$ is affine.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant a variety embedded in $\Bbb{P}^{n^2}$ ( $\Bbb{P}^{n^2}$ minus the subvariety $\det=0$). Ok so the OP wants to use the Venorese map to show it is affine, I got it. @AlexYoucis